# Java Web Application failed to deploy

Tags: java, sql, servlets

I am learning CRUD with java by using sql server database . As far i understand i did everything correctly but when i run the application ,its always return message application failed to deployed ..Here is the error message i got ..

**compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server
GlassFish Server is running.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CRUD_News\build\web
GlassFish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CRUD_News\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1048: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)**

Here is the screen shot of my project ..

[image]

Here is the out put when i run the application ..
[image]

Comment: Did you look at the server log as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the project with Tomcat.
Tomcat is best on Java